# Load Balancing using Apache mod_jk.c (3791): missing uri map for localhost

Tags: tomcat

For a requirment, I need to do load balancing for a web application.

I am struggling with the below issue. Please see the log

```
[Tue Jan 06 15:20:06 2015] [10548:14728] [debug] jk_shm_attach::jk_shm.c (337): Attached shared memory memory [1] size=3072 free=0 addr=0x50aa80
[Tue Jan 06 15:20:06 2015] [10548:14728] [debug] jk_child_init::mod_jk.c (3266): Initialized mod_jk/1.2.40
[Tue Jan 06 15:20:55 2015] [10548:11696] [debug] jk_translate::mod_jk.c (3623): missing uri map for localhost:/eimsgoed
[Tue Jan 06 15:20:55 2015] [10548:11696] [debug] jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (3791): missing uri map for localhost:/eimsgoed
[Tue Jan 06 15:21:56 2015] [10548:11696] [debug] jk_translate::mod_jk.c (3623): missing uri map for localhost:/eimsgoed
[Tue Jan 06 15:21:56 2015] [10548:11696] [debug] jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (3791): missing uri map for localhost:/eimsgoed
```

/eimsgoed is the application I deployed in tomcat instances.

Please see my workers.properties files

=============================

```
worker.list=balancer

worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.port=9004
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost

worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat2.port=9024
worker.tomcat2.host=localhost

worker.tomcat3.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat3.port=9012
worker.tomcat3.host=localhost


worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balance_workers=tomcat1,tomcat2,tomcat3

worker.list=jkstatus
worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

My httpd.conf file

=============

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

# Path to workers.properties
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

# Path to jk logs
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log

# Jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel debug

# Jk log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

# JkOptions for forwarding
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

# JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"



JkMount /eimsgoed balancer
JkMount /status jkstatus
```

My server.xml of all 3 tomcat instances

==============================

tomcat 1 instance

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
 <Connector port="9004" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="9003" />

 <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat1">
```

tomcat 2 instance

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
 <Connector port="9024" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="9023" />
 <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat2">
```

tomcat 3 instance

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
 <Connector port="9012" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="9011" />

 <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat3">
```

Where I am going wrong here in the URI?

```
[Tue Jan 06 15:21:56 2015] [10548:11696] [debug] jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (3791): missing uri map for localhost:/eimsgoed
```

For information, I am using Tomcat 7, Apache HTTP Server 2.4.10 and Tomcat Mod_JK connector 1.2.40, Windows 7 operating system

Please advice me on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see any error in configuration. Maybe an issue with Apache 2.4 and JK.

There is another way to configure a load balancer, using mod_proxy:

https://serverfault.com/questions/604615/apache-mod-proxy-balancer-tomcat-load-balancing-should-not-redirect-until-we

And Here:

http://chandank.com/application-server/tomcat/tomcat-load-balancer-using-mod-proxy-and-session-sticky

Comment: Thanks Marcus.  I am presently working as per your suggesstion.

Comment: @SaravananSivaji have u got success .. can u suggest me..even i too got the same error

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly the same as the answer given to specify JKMount in VirtualHost, but instead of copying the same configuration, you could just specify the JKMountCopy=On. Here is how it looks:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"
    SSLEngine on
    ...
    JkMountCopy On
</VirtualHost>
```

The thing is that this configuration is not inherited by virtual hosts and you have to specify this directive to inherit it.

Comment: Since: 1.2.26 you can also add
    `JkMountCopy All` in the global section

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I almost have the same configuration as you.

I added the `VirtualHost` mapping in the `httpd.conf` file and it start working.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName localhost
  JKMount /TCSession/* lb
</VirtualHost>
```